# How to get the password from Windows Application?

Tags: passwords, data-recovery

I have an application call Metatrader 5. I had logged in way before and now I lost my password. The login could be seen but the password is hidden. I want to know if there is a way to get the hidden password?

See the image:
[image: image got]

I want to get my password. Do anyone have anything to say?

Comment: You can try password unmasker utilities..

Comment: You can drop it on a debugger. Then run the file and step toward the authorization part.

Comment: @SoufianeTahiri Is there any reference available for that?

Comment: @AidenStewart Guess thats a long procedure. Is there any automatic way out for that?

Comment: @JafferWilson Sorry, there are no automated tools. It requires some manual work, and experience with a debugger.

Answer (score 2):

A not too technical solution is using an unmasking tool to unmask those asterisks in browsers and software.

These are 3rd-party unmasking utilites:

1. [Bullets Pass View](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/bullets_password_view.html)
2. [Encrypted Reg View](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/encrypted_registry_view.html)
3. [Asterisk Password Spy](https://securityxploded.com/asterisk-password-spy.php) (I have used)
4. [Kernel Password Unmask](https://www.nucleustechnologies.com/Unmask-Password-Show-Reveal-Stars.html)

I don't know *Metatrader 5* but there is a Windows built-in tool for this situation which usually used in organizations and enterprise companies.

Go to `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Credential Manager` then click on `Windows Credentials`, Then possibly you see your password there.